# Pyspark SQL get ALL highest values from group and assess for dupes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider this dataframe:

```
+----------+------+--+
|    person| style| n|
+----------+------+--+
|        P1|     A| 1|
|        P2|     A| 1|
|        P2|     B| 2|
|        P3|     A| 1|
|        P3|     B| 2|
|        P3|     C| 2|
|        P4|     A| 2|
|        P4|     B| 2|
+----------+------+--+
```

The goal is to determine the preferred style for each person.  Preference has tricky rules, however!

1. If a person has a single style (e.g. `P1`), that style is their preference regardless of the number of observations `n`.
2. If a person has 2 or more styles where one clearly has the greatest `n` (e.g. `P2` style `B`) then that is the preference.
3. Now it gets harder.  If a person has 3 or more styles where at least 2 `n` are the highest value and are *the same*, then all styles with the highest `n` are considered preferences (e.g. `P3` styles `B` and `C`)
4. If a person has 2 or more styles where `n` is the same for all, *NO* preference is set (e.g. `P4`).  Note that if `P3` had one more `n` for style `A` (to make it `2`) then it would also fall into this category.

Before experimenting with SPARK I would simply `GROUP` and `ORDER` by `person` and would iterate over these results, sniffing for `max(n)` and in general programmatically handling it.  But I am new to SPARK and I understand that one should avoid iterating and collecting and such.  I think my target output frame is

```
+----------+------+--+
|    person| style| n|
+----------+------+--+
|        P1|     A| 1|
|        P2|     B| 2|
|        P3|     B| 2|
|        P3|     C| 2|
+----------+------+--+
```

There are several good examples of finding the *highest* value in a column in a `GROUP BY` but that doesn't satisfy rule #3 or #4 above.

I am guessing some sort of a self-join where `(count(max(n)) <> count(*)) or count(max(n)) = 1` but I am no expert in SQL.

Not to make this a contest but as a comparison, in MongoDB I would get styles and counts into an *array* for each person and then use `$reduce` to walk the array and apply logic to see if `n` was the same in each style, then "marking" the document (not the array) with a code indicating the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark the rows with condition 4 and remove them after you do the usual `row_number` trick (actually `rank` here, because you want to keep ties according to condition 3):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'cond', 
    (F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('person')) > 1) & 
    (F.min('n').over(Window.partitionBy('person')) == 
     F.max('n').over(Window.partitionBy('person'))
    )
).withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy('person').orderBy(F.desc('n')))
).filter('rn = 1 and not cond').drop('cond', 'rn')

df2.show()
+------+-----+---+
|person|style|  n|
+------+-----+---+
|    P2|    B|  2|
|    P3|    B|  2|
|    P3|    C|  2|
|    P1|    A|  1|
+------+-----+---+
```